# Кастомизация виджетов Андроид: наследование стандартных или создание собственных?

Tags: android, интерфейс

Настал момент, когда приходится задумываться о том, как сделать красивый интерфейс. Стандартные виджеты не дают нужную гибкость, поэтому либо меняй их, либо создавай собственные виджеты. Но зачем изобретать велосипед? Хотя, я вот попытался что-то сделать со стандартным виджетом, но добиться желаемого не получилось. Подумал сделать собственный виджет и засомневался: а не будет ли это перечить принятой практике? Я вроде слышал, что принято переделывать стандартные виджеты...

Так что обычно делают программисты: делают все сами как им хочется или пилят стандартные виджеты пока не добъются результата? Или делают как им удобнее?

Благодарю всех, кто ответил, и обещаю постараться впредь так не делать (я про оффтоп). Первый раз на сайте, вы уж извините меня =).

Comment: Многие участники этого сообщества (не я =) ) видят в таких вопросах злостный оффтоп, я бы советовал вам сформулировать вопрос немного поконкретнее

Comment: Здесь все просто. Если стандартный виджет можно улучшить незначительными корректировками, то лучше наследоваться. Если вам требуется что то принципиально другое, то создать собственный , который в любом случае будет все же наследоваться от `View` или `ViewGroup`, иначе проделанная работа, скорее всего, не будет стоить результата. Вообще, программист - хозяин, он же барин, как вы считаете вам лучше реализовать задуманное, так и делайте

Comment: Да и EditText будет очень тяжко с нуля писать, лучше даже и не задумываться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственное гарантированное правило, которое я для себя вывел по созданию красивых интерфейсов гласит:

> Переделывай до тех пор, пока не посмотришь и не скажешь - А это
>   красиво и круто.

А добиваться это наследую типовые виджеты или использовать сторонние библиотеки или отрисовывать через onDraw и Сanvas собственные View - это вопрос второстепенный. В зависимости от ситуации используют все варианты обычно.